Change owner of token account if I have token account private key
This is a very weird scenario:
There is a token account (5nAG5CdJgck1gCpbRPC56nQW5bZQWUzZA3f2YTyEC4g9)
We have private key of this token account
But we don't have private key of the owner (31P96GiVd8eebDo9evfT16GER4iJEkQqrvdKh77F4yST)
Can we change the owner to this token account?
If you provide a solution and I can do it I will financially grateful.
P.S. I'm a JavaScript dev.

Simply put, you can't. Only the owner of an account can reassign ownership of a token account, so without the private key of the owner, you cannot do anything.

thank you so much man
